# Showing Missing field "image" in Merchant Listings of Google Search Console

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

I added a sitemap. Then I found the Missing field "image" error in Merchant Listings of Google Search Console for the website [dofurni](https://dofurni.com) which is developed in Magento 2.4.3. Please refer to the attached screenshot.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

I tried checking the robot.txt but nothing is block for fetching to google search console.

Comment: did you got any solution? I am also facing the same issue